Does Cauchy stress tensor act on $SO(3)$?
I have some confusions surrounding the nature of the Cauchy stress tensor.
Ostensibly, the stress tensor takes some vector normal to a surface and gives another vector which is a linear transformation of that vector. What confuses me is that the stress tensor, despite it being represented by a matrix, does not seem to follow the traditional linearity principles, like homogeneity under scalar multiplication.
Also, a tensor to my knowledge is supposed to be a multilinear map between vector spaces and their duals, but in the case of the stress tensor the domain seems to be just the unit normal vectors, which comprise the group $SO(3)$, which is not a vector space.

The unit normal vectors is not SO(3). SO(3) is (diffeomorphic to) the collection of all lines passing through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The normal vector is arbitrary, and can be used for any surface, whether real or hypothetical, at a spatial location.

Cauchy’s theorem, under standard physical laws of continuous bodies, proves that the stress vector $s$ at $p$, referred to the normal unit $n$, has the form
$$s(p,n)_k = \sigma(p)_{kj} n_j.$$
Above, I was referring to orthonormal Cartesian coordinates, and I used the summation convention over related indices. The $9$ scalar functions $p\mapsto \sigma(p)_{ij}$ are known and depend on the physical properties of the continuum at $p$ and also on the chosen basis of the vector space.
The above function is only defined on $S^2$ since $n$ is a generic unit vector. However, it is possible to define a linear function (in particular homogeneous) on the whole vector space as
$$\mathbb{R}^3 \ni v \mapsto ||v|| \sigma(p)_{ij}\frac{v_j}{||v||}{\bf e}_i$$
where the right-hand side is, by definition, $0$ if $v=0$.
This function is evidently linear and maps vectors to vectors. As a consequence, varying the orthonormal basis, the sets of coefficients $\{\sigma(p)_{ij}\}_{i,j=1,2,3}$ define the components of a tensor $\sigma(p)$.
In all this description, one assumes that the vector space is equipped with the standard Euclidean metric. In this case, the dual space is naturally identified with its dual space, and, working in orthonormal bases, no distinction between contravariant and covariant components is necessary. With a more general choice of basis, the stress tensor is more conveniently described as a $(1,1)$ tensor instead of a $(0,2)$ tensor. The symmetry property (arising from the angular momentum balance law), $\sigma_{ij}=\sigma_{ji}$ is apparent only with the doubly covariant case.

sorry, I'm not familiar with the tensor jargon, I guess I'm trying to ask if there is no problem if the domain of the stress tensor is S^2 and if I'm correct in thinking that this tensor doesn't fit the general definition of the tensor usually given as multilinear maps. I just thought it was weird that even if you scale the unit vector normal to a surface, the stress tensor should still give the same output vector since both are pointing in the same direction, hence lack of homogeneity.
